# I would like to extract the information from an html page TAG using c#

Tags: c#, html

As in the description, I would like to extract information from an html page. Below the html code. I would like to extract the info from:

`"images/flags/us.gif", 
"mohaa.uwsclan.us:12203/", 
"=|UWS|= Public FreezeTag Test", 
"0/34", 
"ip">45.79.133.140</span><span class="port">:12203"`

I have tried with html agility pack, but without success! Can someone help me? Thanks.
This is the link I would like to extract the information: https://www.gametracker.com/search/mohaa/?query=FreezeTag

```html
<td>
  <a href="/search/mohaa/">
    <img src="/images/game_icons16/mohaa.png" alt="MOHAA" />
  </a>
</td>
<td>
  <a href="/server_info/mohaa.uwsclan.us:12203/">
    <img src="/images/icons/icon16x16_fav.png" alt="" /> =|UWS|= Public FreezeTag Test
  </a>
</td>
<td>
  0/34
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
  <a href="/search/mohaa/US/">
    <img src="/images/flags/us.gif" alt="" class="item_16x11" />
  </a>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="ip">45.79.133.140</span><span class="port">:12203</span>
</td>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is _not_ a free code-writing service. Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I solved the problem by my self. Post the code for everyone.

```
HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='table_lst table_lst_srs']");
            bool newRow = false;
            //LOOP THROUGH THE TABLE NODE AND FIND EACH TR 
            foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("./tr"))
            {
                if (newRow == true) textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("./td"))
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.InnerText.Trim()))
                    {
                        textBox1.Text += WebUtility.HtmlDecode(cell.InnerText.Trim()) + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    newRow = false;
                }
                newRow = true;
            }
```

**Return this list**

```
1.
<MLS> STONER SERVER
22/50
66.23.201.46:12203
dm/mohdm6

2.
#WoV OBJ Public CKR1.1 @ wovclan.com
16/32
185.245.80.71:12203
obj/obj_team1

3.
{AB}<>Sniper/Rifle - V2 + Map Rotation - Mixed Gametype
26/40
95.179.166.106:12203
obj/obj_team2

4.
=|>DooM<|=  S n i p e r / R i f l e
11/32
51.77.141.225:12203
m6l2a

5.
=:AnUbIs:=   FFA  Bring Out Your Dead   anubis.clan.free.fr
13/32
195.154.170.107:12203
obj/obj_team3

etc... etc...
```

Thanks anyway for the advice ;) Mark as solved!

Comment: Edit your question to add your code, instead of adding your code as an answer.